# Does GCM registeration token remain unchanged if app never update and the InstanceID provider never initiate refresh

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using [Google's GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) service in my app. I tried the [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git) and it worked fine for me. But there is one thing regarding the registration token that confuses me.

The sample code inside the function `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` in [RegistrationIntentService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java) has lines to get the token and then uses is to subscribe the topic

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

I understand that the token refresh may be initiated by the system from reading the sample code [MyInstanceIDListenerService.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyInstanceIDListenerService.java), and then I will have to notify the server from the callback function `onTokenRefresh()`.

I found that the function `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` is always called when I tap the notification to open the app, as a result, the registration token will be generated again. My question is, I can set flat at the point when `onTokenRefresh()` to determine if I need to update the server and re-subscribe the topic. But can I safely assume the token will never get changed from app launch?

Comment: Hi, do we really need to re-subscribe all the topics after onTokenRefresh() triggered or GCM server will automatically do it ?

Answer (score 3):

"Does GCM registeration token remain unchanged if app never update and the InstanceID provider never initiate refresh"

The short answer is yes. It never changes. If it does on token refresh will be called. As for the google sample code, there are few vital pieces missing from it which you have to fill up yourself. The first is that `RegistrationIntentService` does not check if the device is already registered. You should save this information in shared preferences.

If the device is already registered there is no need for this bit of code:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token =     instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Now the question arises what happens if you do call execute this code over and over again? I did experiment with that and found that some devices kept giving the same token over and over again but other devices returned different tokens.

Comment: That's where my question is, the quoted code is executed every time when I tap the notification to open the app. On my experiment, the token seems to remain the same. But in case it's different, then I will have to notify the server and re-subscribe. As you mentioned, the token is different on some devices. For that case, I will have to save the current some where and compare with the new token every time when executed.

Comment: Surely you have some problem in your intents? This code should be executed only once per app lifecycle. IN any event saving a flag in the shared preferences that you have already registered should avoid the problem.

Comment: I don't see issue yet as the token remains the same on my device. But you said it will have different value on some other devices, that makes me worry after release. If I open the app by tapping the icon from home, yes, the code will not be executed. It happens when opening it from notification. I could set the flag in the function [InstanceIDListenerService.html#onTokenRefresh()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService.html#onTokenRefresh%28%29), but I also wonder if there is better way if the change is initiated from `getToken()`.

Comment: And what I am asking is why aren't you adding 4 lines of code to check whether already registered and skip the registration?

Comment: Sure, that's easy to do. Let me be more clear, the different token can happen when 1) `onTokenRrfresh()` is called 2) `getToken()` is executed. Scenario 1 is for sure because it's initiated by the Android system and I can set flag here. Scenario 2 would happen randomly(my understanding so far) so I will have to memorize the current value some where and do comparison every time it executes. In your experiment, did you see `onTokenRrfresh()` is always called when scenario 2 happens(which means only scenario 1 exists)? If that's the case, I can simply depend on `onTokenRrfresh()` to set the flag.